# "Попасть в каталажку"

Tags: этимология

Говорят "попасть в каталажку". А что такое "каталажка" изначально? Откуда пошло это слово?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

КАТАЛАЖКА - это жаргонное название тюрьмы, образованное посредством уменьшительного суффикса от *каталаж*, в диалектах использующегося в значении "тесное помещение" (ср.: *каталашка* "камера при волостном управлении для провинившихся крестьян", тобольск.). Каталаж является переоформлением заимствованного из немецкого *такелаж* (Takelage) – "снасти на судне, помещение для них". (Даль; примечание Трубачева к соответствующей словарной статье у Фасмера)

Answer (score 3):

В словаре **Фасмера** читаем:

Каталаж Ближайшая этимология: "поклажа", колымск. (Богораз), Каталажка "котомка", арханг. (Подв.), Каталашка "камера при волостном управлении для провинившихся крестьян", тобольск. (ЖСт., 1899, вып. 4, стр. 495). **Темное слово**. Комментарии Трубачева: [Метатеза из Такелаґж, как правильно указывал еще Даль2, II, стр. 96. -- Т.] Страницы: 2,209